# How to write only specified properties using properties-maven-plugin:write-project-properties

Tags: maven

I am trying to write the Git properties to a specified file using `properties-maven-plugin`. For that I am using the below code:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>ru.concerteza.buildnumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jgit-buildnumber-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>git-buildnumber</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>extract-buildnumber</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<!--write project properties to file -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputFile>${project.basedir}/../build-info.tmp</outputFile>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>revision</name>
                        <value>${revision}</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>buildnumber</name>
                        <value>${buildnumber}</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now my questions are:

1. It is giving branch, build number, commitscount, tag, branch, etc., But I want to extract only revision and build number from the `maven-jgit-buildnumber-plugin` using properties plugin.
2. I want to rename them also. For example `git.buildnumber` as `buildnumber` and `git.revision` as `revision`.
3. Is there any possible way that I can take the `buildnumber` from the command prompt from the user manually?

Can anyone suggest me through this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a hint: `properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2` is almost 7 years old. The latest version is [`1.0.0`](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.codehaus.mojo%22%20AND%20a%3A%22properties-maven-plugin%22). The latest [maven-jgit-buildnumber-plugin](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|maven-jgit-buildnumber-plugin) is 1.2.10.

Comment: Thank you Gerold. But it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: I would suggest to take a look http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/create-mojo.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working.... by keeping it in a profile and giving the command clean install -P profilename -Dversion=16

```
    <plugin>
                <groupId>com.keyboardsamurais.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-timestamp-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyName>date</propertyName>
                    <timestampPattern>EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy Z</timestampPattern>
                    <timeZone>IST</timeZone>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>ru.concerteza.buildnumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jgit-buildnumber-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>git-buildnumber</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>extract-buildnumber</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <revisionProperty>revision</revisionProperty>
                            <buildnumberProperty>version</buildnumberProperty>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>revision</name>
                                    <value>${revision}</value>
                                </property>
                                <property>
                                    <name>date</name>
                                    <value>${date}</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.internetitem</groupId>
                <artifactId>write-properties-file-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>write-properties-file</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>write-properties-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filename>build-info.tmp</filename>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/../</outputDirectory>
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>revision</name>
                                    <value>${revision}</value>
                                </property>
                                <property>
                                    <name>date</name>
                                    <value>${date}</value>
                                </property>
                                <property>
                                    <name>version</name>
                                    <value>${version}</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: can we append to existing properties file ?